# How can I download a OneDrive file with Office365 REST API into a Ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, office365, email-attachments, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app, and I'd like to integrate some Office365 features.

For instance : I would like to download a file from OneDrive and then attach it to an Email in order to send it via Outlook rest API.

I found this [get Item content OneDrive REST API](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm) but I dont understand how to use it.

I understand that I have to send a GET request (formated as explained in msdn.microsoft.com) with Rails, which will then provide me a "*a pre-authenticated download URL*" to download the file.

Then I will have to send a second GET request with this *a pre-authenticated download URL* to start the download, but I don't understand how to deal with the Response in order to save the file into a variable.

How can I retrieve the file into a variable of my Ruby on Rails App, so that I can attach it to an Email with an Outlook REST API to send it from my own Rail controller ?

Also this workflow is really not optimized in term of Bandwidth and Processing (3 REST API request + 1 download + 1 upload), it will work.

However if it exist a single REST API that direclty attach a OneDrive file to an email to send it, that would **ease a lot my life, save energy, save money from Microsoft datacenter, and spare the planet ecology**.

Any tutorial, examples, or more explanatory doc would be much appreciated.

--- EDIT ---
Adding link to the email is not wished as the email may have to be send to someone outside of Office365 users, and public link are a security issue for confidential documents.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single REST API call you can make currently to do what you want, although being able to easily attach a file from OneDrive to a new email message is a great scenario for Microsoft Graph API, it just isn't supported right now.

If you want to attach the file, you need to do as you mentioned, download the contents of the file, and then upload it again as an attachment to the message.

However, I'd recommend sending a link to the file instead, even though you mentioned you don't want to do that. OneDrive for Business now supports "company shareable links" which are scoped to just the user's organization instead of being available totally anonymously.

Something else to consider: The security concerns of sending an anonymous link aren't that different than sending an attached file. In fact, the anonymous link can be more secure, because access to the file can be monitored and revoked in the future (unlike the attachment, which will always be out there).

Comment: Ok but could you answer the question ? => How can I retrieve the file into a variable of my Ruby on Rails App, so that I can attach it to an Email with an Outlook REST API to send it from my own Rail controller ? As I dont want to store the file in between the download and the email sending. Thanks to clarify